# Delegates in Forms How to destroy

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, memory-leaks, delegates

I have in a WindowsForms solution a Form that has memory leaks problems. 
The form is opened with a button on the MainForm.
After opening it multiple times an unhandled exception terminates the application.

That form has a private instance in the MainForm, and is closed or is recreated following some logic rules.

That child form contains some delegates from the MainForm.
I suppose the delegates could cause memory leaks. Probably when the form is closed and or recreated the ancient instances could be kept in the memory linked with the delegates.

How and where to "destroy" the delegates in a Form?

```
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize() ' here?

Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleDestroyed(e As System.EventArgs) ' or here
  Me._MyDelegate1 = Nothing
  Me.DlgDelegate1 = Nothing
  Me.DlgDelegate2 = Nothing
```

Comment: Will the formclosed event work? Can you create the subform instance in a `using` block?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `Form.Dispose` method is the most appropriate place for cleanup like this. It is likely already been overridden in the designer, in which case you'll need to move it to your code file.

Here is another post with regards to overriding `Fom.Dispose` that should help. [How do I extend a WinForm's Dispose method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052147/how-do-i-extend-a-winforms-dispose-method)