# How to implement my own Dispose method for a WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I'd like to perform certain operations (saving a log file, for example) in the `Disposed` method of a Windows Form, in my `MyForm.cs` file. However, the `Dispose()` method is automatically generated by the designer at build time (into `MyForm.designer.cs`, and I get

> Type 'MyForm' already defines a member called 'Dispose' with the same
>   parameter types

What would be the proper way of doing what I want? It seems to me that manually editing the "designer" file isn't a good idea.

Comment: Manually editing the designer file is the way to do this.

Comment: Using Closing event instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052147/how-do-i-extend-a-winforms-dispose-method